# Почему-то не срабатывает метод concat()

Tags: javascript

Надо чтобы строка повторилась слитно 3 раза. При этом repeat не пользоваться. Решил через добавление в массив циклом `for` и потом в строку `join('')`.

Обнаружил, что ошибка в `concat`. А отчего он не хочет здесь работать?

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  let me = ''
  let i = 0
  while (i < num) {
    me.concat(str)
    //me += str //если вставить эту строку вместо concat, let me изменится
    i++
  }
  return me;
}
let a = repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: В concat ошибки нет. А вот в программе есть. Попробуйте почитать документацию

Comment: в документации не нашел ответа, конечно конкат отрабатывает, но почему он не меняет переменную me? Если его заменить на   me += str , то переменная изменится. Хотя казалось бы конкат и   me += str выдают одинаковый результат.

Comment: А где документации написано что `concat` должен что-то менять? Он **возвращает новую строку**, а куда вы её денете не его дело. Может просто потеряете (как в вашем случае) может присвоите другой переменной или ещё что-то…

Answer (score 1):

Что касается ошибки в коде,то в документации говориться:

```
Метод concat() объединяет текст из двух или более строк и возвращает новую строку.
```

Это значит что строка не мутирует (не изменяется). Вообще, в JS строки никогда не мутируют, только массивы и то не всегда например в методе `splice` происходит мутация.

*В любом учебном задании преследуется цель чтобы учащийся усвоил какую-то тему, поэтому очень важно в вопросе цитировать дословно все условия задачи, это поможет дать наиболее подходящий ответ. Т.е. нужно понимать какая тема в данном случае изучается `Методы массивов` или `Методы строк`, а может вообще `Циклы и условные конструкции` - во всех этих случаях ответы будут разными.*

Если нужна реализация без `repeat` то вот она, тут используются методы массивов (но можно было бы обойтись циклом):

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  return Array(num).fill(str).join('');
}

let a = repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
console.log(a);
```

Что касается варианта с `concat` (методов строк) я бы использовал его так, хотя тут можно было обойтись простым `join`:

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  return str.concat(...Array(num -1).fill(str))   
}
console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3))
```

Comment: забыл добавить, была просьба repeat не пользоваться

Comment: @eugene, добавьте это в описание вопроса

Comment: при начальном объявлении  let me = ''; Затем в цикле добавляется к переменной me, используя  me += str при этом изменяется me. Задачка на тему алгоритмов. Но мне не понятно почему не изменил переменную me метод concat ?  А  me += str успешно изменил. ПС. код немного изменил под этот вопрос

Comment: потому что += имеет присваивание, он не мутирует сроку, он ее переписывает в другую (в данном случае ту же) переменную

Comment: кажется разобрался, если изменить строку на     me = me.concat(str)
переменная me меняется

Comment: да абсолютно верно, если мой ответ помог разобраться отметьте его

Answer (score 0):

`concat()` не изменяет строку, а создает новую с измененным текстом.

Правильный код:

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  let me = ''
  let i = 0
  while (i < num) {
    me = me.concat(str)
    i++
  }
  return me;
}
let a = repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: в целом тут `i` избыточна. `num--` хватит без дополнительных счетчиков

Comment: да, спс, я уже несколько ранее нашел эту ошибку, что надо  me = me.concat(str)